# qTip inline onClick fires twice on AJAX content

Tags: php, ajax, qtip

I have a page populated by a database using AJAX and PHP.  There is a link to "add the item to a list" and when you click the link a qTip box pops up over it confirming it has been added.  When I try to use qTip to do this though, **the onClick event that I use to add the item fires twice.**

This is the response function for AJAX that populates the page and then initializes the tooltip for the newly created div.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { document.getElementById("contentdiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; updateTooltip();}
}
```

This is my tooltip initialization function

```
function updateTooltip() {  
    $(".Tooltip").qtip({
       content: "<a href='blah.html' target='_blank'>Item Added</a>",
       show: 'click',
       hide: 'none',
       style: { 
           width: 500,
           height: 12,
           name: 'light'
       },
       position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'center',
                tooltip: 'center'
            }
        }
     });     
}
```

This is the PHP code that generates the link with the onClick event

```
echo "<a class='Tooltip' target='_blank' onClick='addItem();'> Add To List </a>";
```

onClick only fires twice when I use qTip.  It works perfectly fine otherwise with addItem() firing only once when you click once.

Comment: Where is the `addItem()` function?

Comment: Does not matter.  Even if I am using alert() it gives two alerts